# An image on the left and data on the right -- how to create the layout for this?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a grid in a wpf application. I want to put an image on the left and next to it, on the right, in the same row some multi-line text/information. And so in each row:

```
=====================================
Image1    field1: data1
          field2: data1
          field3: data1
          field4: data1
          field5: data1
          field6: data1
=====================================
Image2    field1: data2
          field2: data2
          field3: data2
          field4: data2
          field5: data2
          field6: data2
=====================================
```

Of course, the image should have approximately the same height as all the fields to the right of it.

How can I do that? Meaning, the layout itself. I'm kind of confused on all the ways it can be achieved. There seems to be many.

Comment: With WPF you think about all of the neat layout tools you could use and then use a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a grid with a stackpanel to hold the fields, heres an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="leftTopImage"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="0"/>

    <Image x:Name="leftBottomImage"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="1"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="field1Top"/>
        <TextBlock Text="field2Top"/>
        <TextBlock Text="field3Top"/>
        <TextBlock Text="field4Top"/>
        <TextBlock Text="field5Top"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="field1Bottom"/>
        <TextBlock Text="field2Bottom"/>
        <TextBlock Text="field3Bottom"/>
        <TextBlock Text="field4Bottom"/>
        <TextBlock Text="field5Bottom"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Put this code on your design, and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: thanks. when it's bigger than the form, how can I make the grid have the vertical scroll bar?

Comment: ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" doesn't help

Comment: Actually, the vertical scroll bar appears automatically, but you can add manually by surrounding the grid with a ScrollViewer.

Comment: <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        //yourGrid
    </ScrollViewer>

Answer (score 1):

You could use a grid... Three columns and six rows.  Then use a row span on the first column.  Something like

```
        <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.RowSpan="6"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: @AlanCoromano I wouldn't have thought so and it keeps your labels and fields aligned.  I think it just comes down to user preference.